# Odd Bulk Insert Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I'm trying to debug a SQL Server 2008 bulk insert, and I'm getting errors that don't really add up.

The T-SQL is

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].SYNC_OFFERDISCOUNTS 
FROM 'c:\inetpub\ftproot\ecometrydev\offer-discounts.csv' 
WITH (BATCHSIZE = 500, FIRSTROW = 2, ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIELDTERMINATOR ='||^^||')
```

And my errors are

> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (truncation) for row 2, column 72 (ACTION_TYPE).
>
> Msg 4863, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 3 Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row
>   3, column 72 (ACTION_TYPE).
>
> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Bulk
>   load data conversion error (truncation) for row 4, column 72
>   (ACTION_TYPE).

And so on, up to row 12, at which point 10 errors are reached, and the whole thing is shut down.  My database schema and the partial contents of the CSV are below.  It looks to me like a single character `I` is getting inserted for `ACTION_TYPE`, so I'm not sure why this error is happening.

**EDIT**

Especially frustrating is the fact that there are only **71** columns in the file, and the last column of the file corresponds to `ACTION_TYPE`.

**/EDIT**

I've already tried increasing this column to `varchar(50)`, with the thought that maybe the legacy system that created this csv was slipping in some hidden unicode nonsense, but that changed nothing.

I know there's a lot of crap here.  I've already counted over all those zeroes time and again, and it always ends up that that single `I` character is exactly slotted to go into the `ACTION_TYPE` column.  I'm hoping there's some obscure error somewhere that an expert here can spot.

---

**CSV**

DISCOUNTTABLE||^^||MULTIQTY_001||^^||MULTIQTY_002||^^||MULTIQTY_003||^^||MULTIQTY_004||^^||MULTIQTY_005||^^||MULTIQTY_006||^^||MULTIQTY_007||^^||MULTIQTY_008||^^||MULTIQTY_009||^^||DISCOUNTPERCENT_001||^^||DISCOUNTPERCENT_002||^^||DISCOUNTPERCENT_003||^^||DISCOUNTPERCENT_004||^^||DISCOUNTPERCENT_005||^^||DISCOUNTPERCENT_006||^^||DISCOUNTPERCENT_007||^^||DISCOUNTPERCENT_008||^^||DISCOUNTPERCENT_009||^^||DISCOUNTITEM_001||^^||DISCOUNTITEM_002||^^||DISCOUNTITEM_003||^^||DISCOUNTITEM_004||^^||DISCOUNTITEM_005||^^||DISCOUNTITEM_006||^^||DISCOUNTITEM_007||^^||DISCOUNTITEM_008||^^||DISCOUNTITEM_009||^^||DISCOUNTQTY_001||^^||DISCOUNTQTY_002||^^||DISCOUNTQTY_003||^^||DISCOUNTQTY_004||^^||DISCOUNTQTY_005||^^||DISCOUNTQTY_006||^^||DISCOUNTQTY_007||^^||DISCOUNTQTY_008||^^||DISCOUNTQTY_009||^^||DISCOUNTPRICE_001||^^||DISCOUNTPRICE_002||^^||DISCOUNTPRICE_003||^^||DISCOUNTPRICE_004||^^||DISCOUNTPRICE_005||^^||DISCOUNTPRICE_006||^^||DISCOUNTPRICE_007||^^||DISCOUNTPRICE_008||^^||DISCOUNTPRICE_009||^^||DISCOUNTDOL_001||^^||DISCOUNTDOL_002||^^||DISCOUNTDOL_003||^^||DISCOUNTDOL_004||^^||DISCOUNTDOL_005||^^||DISCOUNTDOL_006||^^||DISCOUNTDOL_007||^^||DISCOUNTDOL_008||^^||DISCOUNTDOL_009||^^||ITEMQUANTITY_001||^^||ITEMQUANTITY_002||^^||ITEMQUANTITY_003||^^||ITEMQUANTITY_004||^^||ITEMQUANTITY_005||^^||ITEMQUANTITY_006||^^||ITEMQUANTITY_007||^^||ITEMQUANTITY_008||^^||ITEMQUANTITY_009||^^||DESC1||^^||DISCOUNTUPSELL||^^||USERID||^^||DATE||^^||TIME||^^||STATUS||^^||ROWACTION||^^||
0006||^^||       3000||^^||  999999999||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||       2000||^^||       2000||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||20% OFF $30+ ORDER  ||^^||SAVE 20% ON $30+ ORDER                                                          ||^^||LKWILHEL||^^||20110214||^^||11141050||^^||%D||^^||I||^^||
0023||^^||       5000||^^||  999999999||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||       1500||^^||       1500||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||15% OFF $50+ ORDER  ||^^||SAVE 15% ON $50+ ORDER                                                          ||^^||LKWILHEL||^^||20110214||^^||11013470||^^||%D||^^||I||^^||
0049||^^||       4600||^^||  999999999||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||       3000||^^||       3000||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||     0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||          0||^^||30% OFF $46+ ORDER  ||^^||SAVE 30% ON $46+ ORDER                                                          ||^^||LKWILHEL||^^||20110214||^^||11384810||^^||%D||^^||I||^^||

---

**Columns**

[image]

Comment: I think column 72 data size is smaller than value from csv, could you check column 72 and increase size, then try again.

Comment: @ThitLwinOo - I had the same thought.  I jacked it up to `varchar(50)`, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried to test with a few rows and data size for ACTION_TYPE increased VARCHAR(MAX)?

Comment: @ThitLwinOo - actually, yes.  But SQL gives me odd errors about unexpected end of file.  I've even tried copy pasting the **last two** rows, in the hope that whatever end of file / end of line would get copied over.  The CSV is being created, and tinkered with only in Windows, so I don't think I have any odd unix end of lines...

Answer (score 2):

Determine what the End Of Line (EOL) character(s) is. If the end of line is \r\n (and you've only specified \n) then it could be that the bulk insert is reading into the next line and attempting to truncate what it believes to be the `ACTION_TYPE`.

Use Notepad++ to find out what the EOL character is. Click View > Show Symbol > Show End of Line.

Comment: +1 just for reading through all that (your first upvote on SO!!)  Thanks.  What do you suppose would be the best way to tell if \n is really terminating my lines?  An older version of this system is working and I haven't changed how the csv is generated, so I doubt that's the issue. --- There are spaces in front of a lot of the values headed for numeric columns, which I assume SQL just parsed through.  Again, the older version of this system doesn't seem to mind these spaces.

Comment: A simple way to tell what your EOL characters are is through Notepad++. View > Show Symbols > Show End of Line. CR = \r, LF = \n. Windows based files EOL character is CRLF, Unix files are \n.

I'm also unsure of what column 72 actually refers to. Is it the character column, or do you actually have 72 fields across the table?

Thanks for the first upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the SLOTID column and it should fix the problem.
Assuming SLOTID does not exist as a column in the source file.